# Injecting JSON file to Railway Environment for Firebase Admin NuGet package C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I am trying to figure out how to inject my

```
 Firebase-config.json
```

file to Railway environment without committing it to my repo since its public and this file has all of my keys.
FirebaseAdmin Nuget package for some reason uses the file instead of just creating environment variable for each key it requires an env var that points to said json file and then retrieves the keys from there.

Is there a way to inject the json file to the environment while service is being built. or is there a to generate said file in C# adding the keys to individual env vars and generating the file when services starts.

- Repo url: https://github.com/MgARL/ProxyServerDotNet
- Nuget package url: https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet

Thank you .

I already tried to add each key individually to the environment, but Firebase Admin still looking for the firebase-config.json.

Also tried to search in railway settings for a way to add a file to environment.

Comment: I have the same question. Let me know if you figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1. in railway, create a new environment variable (`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON`) with the *contents* of the credentials json file
2. under settings->build command, write the contents of `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON` to /app/firebase-config.json (i.e. `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS_JSON > /app/firebase-config.json`)
3. set the env variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` to `/app/firebase-config.json`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried what Lambinator suggested. I set up my project so that when it first is started the first thing it does is create the JSON file, then it will continue through the dependency injection by the time it gets to the firebase dependencies my file is already there.

You can check my solution at my project commit [here](https://github.com/MgARL/ProxyServerDotNet/commit/1ee471ae53f14bbe7fccf37767ab9e470723dc6b). The only thing is that I don't know if this is a race condition, but so far it has not given me any errors.